# Cannot Read Cookies in Http Response

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am attempting to automate some tasks on my router.  In order to do this a login is required to get a value called 'stok'.  This value is returned as a cookie from the authentication request.

This is an example of the cookie captured in browser developer tools:

```
Set-Cookie: sysauth=34b2202d165b4316eb87c621df0ae0c9; path=/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=3ced8f80e529c0a378d79e279abfc456
```

The code snippet below is my attempt to log in.  The problem is that the the cookieValue being returned is '34b2202d165b4316eb87c621df0ae0c9' as a string.  The value that I need is the value identified as 'stok'.

```
let authResponse = Http.Request("http://192.168.1.2/cgi-bin/luci",
                                 body = FormValues [ "username", username; 
                                                     "password", password ])

let cookieValue = match authResponse.Cookies.TryFind("sysauth") with
                  | Some x -> x
                  | None _ -> ""
```

I cannot find any method to get at the 'path' and 'stok' values in the cookie.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the `cookieValue`, it should be an [HttpCookie instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie?view=netframework-4.8). And HttpCookie has a [Values property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie.values?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpCookie_Values) that "Gets a collection of key/value pairs that are contained within a single cookie object."

I suspect that `cookieValue.Values.["stok"]` will contain the token you're looking for. If not, try looking through `cookieValue.Values.AllKeys` and see what it contains.

Comment: Note that you might have to use a different method than `TryFind("sysauth")`, since `TryFind` is returning a `string option`. The [HttpCookieCollection docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookiecollection?view=netframework-4.8) don't list a `TryFind` method, so I suspect it's an extension method that, for convenience, just gets the cookie's (single) string value. Try using `.Get("sysauth")`, which is documented to return an HttpCookie instance, and then you should have access to its `.Values` property.